# $\varphi^G$=$\psi^G$ implies that subgroups are conjugate

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, characters

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $\varphi,\psi$ be linear characters of $H$ and $K$ respectively, where $H,K$ are subgroups of $G$.

I'm trying to prove that if the $G$-induced characters of $\varphi,\psi$ are equal (this is, $\varphi^G=\psi^G$) then $H$ and $K$ are conjugate in $G$. Yet I don't know if the result is true either. If it was true, it would conclude another proof that I'm attempting.

If $\varphi^G=\psi^G$, evaluating the function at $1$ we obtain that $|G:H|=|G:K|$ and hence $|H|=|K|$. This makes me think that the result may be true.

I have also proved that $\psi_{H^s\cap K}=\varphi^s_{H^s\cap K}$ for some $s\in G$. Mackey's decomposition formula states that if $S$ is a set of double coset representatives so that $G=\cup_{s\in S}HsK$ is a disjoint union then
$$(\varphi^G)_K=\sum_{s\in S}(\varphi^s_{H^s\cap K})^K.$$

Now, by Frobenius reciprocity it holds $0\not=[\varphi^G,\psi^G]=[(\varphi^G)_K,\psi]=\sum_{s\in S}[(\varphi^s_{H^s\cap K})^K,\psi]=\sum_{s\in S}[\varphi^s_{H^s\cap K},\psi_{H^s\cap K}]$. Thus, there exists $s\in S$ such that $0\not=[\varphi^s_{H^s\cap K},\psi_{H^s\cap K}]$ and hence $\psi_{H^s\cap K}=\varphi^s_{H^s\cap K}$ (as both characters are linear and therefore irreducible).

However, I don't know neither this equality of characters may be relevant, as $H^s\cap K$ may be trivial.

Any hint or suggestion for how to proceed is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There appears to be some literature around the study of such pairs of subgroups, either just named "subgroups inducing the same permutation representation" like in this article titled, well, [Subgroups inducing the same permutation representation](https://core.ac.uk/reader/82146700) by Robert M. Guralnick, or "linked subgroups" in this paper titled [Subgroups of finite soluble groups inducing
the same permutation character](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1997-349-07/S0002-9947-97-01696-6/) by Norberto Gavioli, and more references are given in the introduction of Gavioli's paper.

Guralnick's theorem A seems to answer your claim by the negative by providing the existence of counterexamples under some conditions. I'll quote it here to keep this answer self-contained:

> Theorem A: Suppose $H, K < G$ and $1^G_H = 1^G_K$ with $[G : H] = p^2$. Then either $H = K^g$ for some $g \in G$ or $p^\varepsilon =(q^n- l)/(q-1)$ with $\varepsilon \leq 2$, $n \geq 3$, and $q$ a prime power. Furthermore, for any such $p$, there is a group $G$ with $1^G_H = 1^G_K$ for nonconjugate subgroups $H$ and $K$ with $[G : H] = p^2$.

Gavioli even mentions that linked subgroups need not even be isomorphic. For example, in [Riemannian Coverings and Isospectral Manifolds](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236173678_Riemannian_Coverings_and_Isospectral_Manifolds) by Toshikazu Sunada, article which is cited by Gavioli, pairs of non-isomorphic linked subgroups of the Galois group of a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ are used in order to create isospectral yet non-isometric Riemannian manifolds if I understand correctly.